# Issue using pip3 to install "face_recognition", packages do not match hashes

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, error-handling, python3, pip

When I give command

```
pip3 install face_recognition
```

in the raspberry pi terminal, It shows this error:

> THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.

What to do? I have tried many other versions of raspbian but output is the same.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the quoted error?

Answer (score 1):

Your `pip3` command may have downloaded a corrupted file.

Try again with `pip3 install --no-cache-dir face_recognition`.